# Attribute "rows" no considered in Icefaces ace:list component

Tags: jsf, icefaces-3

I use the Icefaces 3 double list component in my JSF application. Everything works fine, but I cant limit the size of items despite the use of the attribute "rows". I want to have 10 elements and make scroll if there are more. But every time I have all the items displayed consistently.

Tag documentation : http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/list.html

XHTML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="/pages/layer/layout.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <ice:form id="formList">
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="blocContent" layout="block">

                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="blocButton" layout="block">
                        <ice:commandButton id="buttonSave" value="#{msg['save']}"
                            action="#{myBean.doSave}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <ace:panel header="List 1">
                        <ace:listControl id="selectList" position="TOP"
                            style="width:60%; margin: 0 auto 0 auto;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Header list
                            </f:facet>

                            <ace:list id="unassignedElements"
                                value="#{myBean.unassignedElements}"
                                styleClass="subList" dropGroup="textGroup"
                                selectionMode="multiple" rows="10" />

                            <ace:list id="assignedElements"
                                value="#{myBean.assignedElements}"
                                selectionListener="#{myBean.removeAssignedElement}"
                                styleClass="subList" dropGroup="textGroup"
                                selectionMode="multiple" rows="10" />
                        </ace:listControl>
                    </ace:panel>

                </h:panelGroup>
            </ice:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a deficiency in the component. The JIRA for this is http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-10277, we will target this for the EE 4.0 and 4.1 releases. - See more at: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/22698.page#sthash.0jqo4zSA.dpuf